# How to Stop Debugger when i close my child window in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

> I have 3 Window in My WPF Xaml Application.
> 1)MainWindow have two button. one is open a project, second button is create a new project. user can click open or create a project button. it will open my second window. In that time i need to close my mainwindow(Only show My second Window).
> 2) second window have two labelbox,two textbox,two button. If user enter project name in textbox field, choose the location in location field. After click the create button. That button will open the my third window(that time i need to close my second window and open the third window)--only show my second window.
> 3) third window have display some paragraph or something... when i close the third window i need to stop the debugging the program(shutdown the my all application). how to do it.(in my application i close the my third window. window only closed. project still running. debugging not stopped. if anyone give the idea.

Comment: Very hard to tell without seeing any code at all, but if the application doesn't stop then likely the main window is still not gone, i.e. maybe it's just hidden, not closed. However havinh 3 separate windows for something like this is a rather strange approach - a more common way would be e.g. a main window which is always open , with a File menu with Open/New entries which when clicked show a modal dialog and then open the project.

Comment: That's correct. My Mainwindow is not closed. it's hidden. so, debugging not stopped. My 3rd window coming from 2nd window button clicked. show my 3rd window can't stopped the debugging.

Comment: MainWindow Code:

Comment: I find your question very confusing. Why can't you just click that red square in visual studio to stop debugging your app? Or is this maybe not debugging at all and you just want the user to be able to shut it down without closing mainwindow explicitly? In which case I suggest you reconsider a window for everything and instead make this a single window app hosts content.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Put it in your question. And delete those.

Comment: Indent each line of code by 4 spaces in your post with at least a line break extra befre and after and it'll format as code.

Comment: how to add my code in comment

Comment: Don't add code in comments, edit your question and add it there

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the flow correctly, Form1 opens Form2 which opens Form3. When the user closes Form3, you want the application to exit. Your project is in WPF.

For this, do two things:

- In the XAML of form 3, add a Closed event handler:

  ```
  <Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.Window2"
    ...........
    Title="Window2" Height="450" Width="800" Closed="Window_Closed">
  ```
- In the handler, call Environment.Exit(0) to exit the application.

  ```
  private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Environment.Exit(0);  // close all windows
  }
  ```